# Removing Individual JavaScript file from MSBuild SonarQube Runner Analysis

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, sonarqube

I am trying to analyse My MVC Project to sonar-Qube.

**My Sonar-Qube version is 5.3 & MSBuild runner version is 1.1**.
**My Visual Studio Version is 2013**

The MVC project is new and only contains code that comes default when you create the project. after analysis it is showing me errors for **jQuery** and **bootstrap** JavaScript files that are in the project.

> **Analysis in Sonar-Qube**

[image]

> **My Batch File that runs MSBuild Sonar Runner Analysis**

```
@ECHO OFF
@setlocal

@REM Start Sonar Begin Process
ECHO.
ECHO Start Sonar Begin Process.
ECHO ==================================================
D:\Nishant\Sonar\MSBuildRunner\1.1\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:"Study:A" /v:1.0.20160118 /n:"Study.A" /d:sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9999

@REM Start Project Build
ECHO.
ECHO Start Project Build.
ECHO ==================================================
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /verbosity:quiet /t:Clean;Rebuild

@REM Start Sonar End Process
ECHO.
ECHO Start Sonar End Process.
ECHO ==================================================
D:\Nishant\Sonar\MSBuildRunner\1.1\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end
```

**Question:** How do I remove these Java-Scripts from analysis as I do not want them to affect my Analysis. As per my understanding I could not give exclude using "sonar-project.properties" [Consider to add a project-level file settings back, similar to the sonar-project.properties](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-124).

**Note:** I also do want to include my personal Java-Scripts to be in analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sonar.exclusions` property (see [docs](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreFiles)).

Moreover since JavaScript plugin 2.10, minified files are excluded from analysis by default. So it will work for example for `bootstrap.min.js` (but not for `bootstrap.js` which is probably not minified).

Comment: Thanks. I had looked into that document but was not able to understand much initialy. But after little working around on site was able to do it.